# The movie "can't/couldn't"/shouldn't" be good.It is directed by novice

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

> The movie can't/couldn't/shouldn't be good.It is directed by novice.

My approach:

I am confused between shouldn't and can't.

Shouldn't because i am sure the movie isn't good because it is directed by novice.

Can't because there is a possibility that movie can't be good.

Comment: Since those are all three of them perfectly valid and normal constructions, you need to ask an actual question, which you have not yet done that I can see.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you would use "can't" in the context of talking about an unknown (whether the movie is any good), and "shouldn't" very often in the case of a contradiction.

E.G.

> *heading in to the movie*
>      Guy 1: It can't be any good; it's directed by *a* novice!
>      Guy 2: We'll see...
>
> *coming out of the movie*
>      Guy 2: What'd you think?
>      Guy 1: It shouldn't be any good - it was produced in a basement with a $5 budget - but it is!